# android kernel sys_call_hook can't across my hook function

Tags: android, linux

recently, i learned how to hook android goldfish kernel 2.6, i wrote hook.c like this:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/moduleparam.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <linux/semaphore.h>
#include <asm/cacheflush.h>
#include <linux/string.h>

void **sys_call_table;

asmlinkage int (*original_call_open) (const char*, int, int);

asmlinkage int (*original_call_read) (unsigned int, char*, int);

asmlinkage int our_sys_read(unsigned int fd, char * buf, int count){

if(fd == 0 && count == 1){
    printk("有文件正在被读取intercept 0x%02X", buf[0]);
}

return original_call_read(fd, buf, count);
}

asmlinkage int our_sys_open(const char* file, int flags, int mode)
{
    //联系人 /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db
    //通话记录       /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/telephony.db
    //短信记录  /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db
    char * contact = "/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db";
    char * telephony = "/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/telephony.db";
    char * sms = "/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db";
    if (strcmp(file, contact) == 0){
       printk("应用程序正在读取手机的联系人记录！！！\n");
    }
   if (strcmp(file, telephony) == 0){
    printk("应用程序正在读取手机的通话记录！！！\n");
   }
   if (strcmp(file, sms) == 0){
    printk("应用程序正在读取手机的短信记录！！！\n");
   }


// printk("A file was opened\n%s\n%d\n%d\n",file,flags,mode);
   return original_call_open(file, flags, mode);
 }

int init_module()
{

sys_call_table = (void*)0xc0022f24;
original_call_open = sys_call_table[__NR_open];
original_call_read = sys_call_table[__NR_read];

sys_call_table[__NR_open] = our_sys_open;
sys_call_table[__NR_read] = our_sys_read;
return 0;
}

void cleanup_module()
{
// Restore the original call
sys_call_table[__NR_open] = original_call_open;
sys_call_table[__NR_read] = original_call_read;
}
```

and next is my apk's main activity:

```
enter code here

package com.nijian;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.CursorJoiner.Result;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String contactUpload = "";

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
            null, null);
    try {
        while (people.moveToNext()) {
            int nameFieldColumnIndex = people
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
            String contact = people.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex);
            int numberFieldColumnIndex = people
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
            String number = people.getString(numberFieldColumnIndex);

            System.out.println(contact + "-" + number);
            contactUpload = contactUpload.concat(contact + "-" + number);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView.setText(contactUpload);
    people.close();
//  new connect().execute();
}
```

}

My app visit contacts, but when i use cat /proc/kmsg it doesn't show my kernel info. Can anyone could help me? thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Across several days learning, i get the right answer, oh ...it's a horrible process. now, let's to answer this question~~

```
if (strcmp(file, contact) == 0){
   printk("应用程序正在读取手机的联系人记录！！！\n");
}
```

upper program is the key to solve this question, we know an APK file will use api to read contacts, but in my program i use strcmp() to compare strings. And the apis will not use "/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db",lick this string. Maybe it will use "/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db/data...."
So we should use strstr() to compare these.
At last is the correct program:

```
if (strcmp(file, contact)) == 0 || strstr(file, contact) != NULL){
     printk("应用程序正在读取手机的联系人记录！！！");
}
```

Comment: Unlikely.  Your actual problem is most likely that the file was already opened before you began your test.  Remember, it is not your application program which reads the contacts database, but rather another program entirely, which is typically started up shortly after boot and performs operations when authorized application programs request them via IPC.  Of course you should not be hard coding paths in a kernel module anyway.

Comment: it's cool, you are right~~but i want to know the better way to hook kernel call, because you say the hard way to coding paths is not better! thank your comment, and wish you can reply me. @ChrisStratton